# How to ignore hidden series when clicking on a legend using highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a charts done in highcharts in which I show and hide series depending on a checkbox (if the user clicks on a checkbox and all series are shown, if he unchecks the checkbox, some series are hidden).
It is working great.
Now I have an issue with the legends in the chart: if the series are hidden and the users enables a legend, the segment of all series (hidden or not) are shown in the chart.

I would like to handle the click item so I only handle series that are being shown. 
To do that, I created an eventhandler for the legendItemClick event.
Inside it, I am able to access the legend (using this) but I am only able to call functions in a legend level, affecting all series. Is there anyway I could get to a series level?

Thanks!

Edit: created a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JLkGm/1/
Steps to reproduce:
1- unmark the checkbox
2- click twice in john + joe
Note that the segment related to Jane + Janet will show up
I would like to prevent this segment from showing if the checkbox is not checked.

ps: sorry for the js code in the checkbox event handler, we are using coffeescript, the original code was this one

```
toggleCompareData: (toggle) ->
        columnName = COLUMN_HIGHCHARTS_TOKEN + @secondaryPrefix
        if toggle
            for serie in @chart.series
                serie.show() if serie.stackKey is columnName
        else
            for serie in @chart.series
                serie.hide() if serie.stackKey is columnName
```

Comment: Do you have any code to attach to exemplify your problem?

Comment: I will make something on fiddle, just a sec

Comment: Well, one complication is that using `linkedTo` makes the `show()` function on a series also show the linked series. I'm not sure how to easily avoid this.

Comment: even with linkedTo, if you add an event to hide the secondary series each time you click the legend item, then you can manually do the hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3309

Comment: Thanks! The link you created seems to present a solution, I will take a look into it once I have the chance :) thanks!